# unable to install phpunit with composer

Tags: phpunit, local, composer-php

basically i have this composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "phpunit/phpunit",
    "require": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "3.8.*@dev"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Sebastian Bergmann",
            "email": "sebastian@phpunit.de"
        }
    ]
}
```

and when I go to run "composer install" i get the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 3.8.*@dev -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[3.8.x-dev].
    - phpunit/phpunit 3.8.x-dev requires phpunit/php-code-coverage 1.3.*@dev -> no matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I have no clue as to what that means? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before actually answering your question:

You have called your project `phpunit/phpunit` and you have a require on `phpunit/phpunit`. That is a circular dependency. You should call your project something else.

Also, I doubt that you are "Sebastian Bergmann" so you should change the name of the author and email address in your composer file.

Ok, for you actual question, Composer by default won't install dev packages. You need to explicitly tell it to install dev packages by putting

"minimum-stability": "dev"

in your root composer.json file for your project, or change the require for PHPUnit to not use the dev package e.g.

```
"require": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.8.*"
},
```

Unless you are actively debugging an issue in another package, it's unlikely that you actually want to use a dev version of that package. You almost always want an actual tagged version.

Comment: Thanks a great deal even though i feel stupid having overlooked the name "sebastian begmann" LOl awful ! The one thing I've learned from this is on the name part. So i've simply renamed the project and of course put my own name, plus specifying minimum stability which solved the problem. Cheers